# Internet connection working only on home WiFi

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, internet

I'm having serious problem with my WiFi connection, respectively with the internet connection.

My laptop is Lenovo EDGE E 530 3259-4DG . I'm able to connect to any WiFi, but then the internet connection is not working. On my WiFi at home (where I installed the Kubuntu 12.04 64bit) , the internet connection is fine.

As a summary, I'm able to connect to other WiFis and always get the IP address, but then the internet connection is not working then. I tried four different WiFi routers and had always the same issue. I have no idea how to solve it. Does it has anything to do with the rights?

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Ok the ip is assigned , now just check this

1) the routing table is populated ?

> route -n

do you have the default route added ?

> Destination     Gateway
>
> 0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0

if you are too lazy and the network is open , just try to ping an ip address, use google public dns , is mnemonic simply 8.8.8.8

if you ping it you are online and the routings are ust fine

2) the point 1 is ok ? now check the dns

> cat /etc/resolv.conf

this will output lines like this

> nameserver XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 
>   some times the XXX.XX... is the IP of your router / AP or the DNS server of you ISP

if nothing present , just add manualy one

> sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf

I think that these 2 steps solve your issue.