# Internet working on only one place ubuntu16.04

Tags: internet

I have a laptop with ubuntu 16.04, 
and an

```
Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

and

```
Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)
```

my problem is, that with my home router everything is working perfectly, so I have internet connection, but if I connect to any other network (doesn't matter if it is wired or wireless) I see that the connetion is made, but there is no internet.
The output of

ifconfig

is the following

```
enp5s0f1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 78:24:af:c9:87:a6  
      inet addr:192.168.0.103  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a1bd:1b23:18a3:aff5/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:46400 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:13061 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:58617291 (58.6 MB)  TX bytes:1612298 (1.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5107 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5107 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:406499 (406.4 KB)  TX bytes:406499 (406.4 KB)

wlp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:19:34:c9:a5:8b  
          inet addr:192.168.0.101  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6f01:97b0:5c1b:c29b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:280 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1417 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:47869 (47.8 KB)  TX bytes:187514 (187.5 KB)
```

I already tried to do for a wireless connection what this post suggests, however no success
[Laptop can only access internet on one network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751219/laptop-can-only-access-internet-on-one-network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this post I managed to solve my issue:
[Internet connection working only on home WiFi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279489/internet-connection-working-only-on-home-wifi)

the problem was, that in

```
/etc/resolv.conf
```

the nameserver was 192.168.0.1
I changed it to 8.8.8.8 as the post suggested, and now everything works fine...